# Storing data entered when signing up

Tags: php, mysql, database, verification

I need to create a sign up page that will store user name email passwords and put them in a database so that the user can then login and access a profile etc.

I have made a database [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFDqU.png) however nothing will go into it. I input one manually but anything I try to do from the webpage won't go to the database.

Code for the webpage: Signup is the page I want displayed and adduser is the code for adding the data to the database.

Signup:

```
    <?php include '../view/header.php';
 ?>
<br>
<br>
<h1 class="light white-text text-lighten-3">Sign up!</h1>
<br>
<br>
<form class="form" id="signup" action="addUser.php" method="post">  


     <div class="form-group ">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email">
    </div>
    <br>
      <div class="form-group ">
            <input id="user_name" type="text" class="validate" name="user_name"required="required">
          <label for="user_name">User Name</label>
        </div>
    <br>
      <div class="form-group col s6">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter a Password">
    </div>
    <br>

    <br>
     <button type="submit" class="orange btn btn-primary">Submit</button>  
</form>  


<?php

include '../view/footer.php';
```

AddUser:

```
<script src="../js/materialize.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/materialize.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../js/init.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = 'root';
$Password ="";
$database = 'commish';

$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $Password, $database);


$email    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email');

$user_name    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'user_name');

$password    = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'password'); 

new_user( $user_name, $password,$email, $con);
function new_user($user_name, $password, $email,$con) 
{
    global $con;
    $query = "INSERT into users (user_name, password, email) VALUES (:user_name, :password, :email)";
    $statement = $con->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(":user_name", $user_name);
    $statement->bindValue(":password", $password);
    $statement->bindValue(":email", $email);
    $statement->execute();
    echo 'Successfully created new user';
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error???

Comment: Make sure that you __know__ what is `PDO` and what is `mysqli`

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bindValue() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(20): new_user('bob', NULL, NULL, Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php on line 26

Comment: There's no `bindValue()` method in `mysqli`. Use [bind_param()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php).

Comment: @EmilyP : You are making it too hard on yourself..Why don't you try the simple and real easy way to do this..! I am going to write an answer to you..!

Comment: @Rajdeep i changed to param but i now have this error : Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php:26 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(20): new_user('bob', NULL, NULL, Object(mysqli)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php on line 26

Comment: @UmairShahYousafzai: Thank you ^-^

Comment: This looks like PDO code, but it's implemented with `mysqli`. If you're just getting started here, convert all that to PDO because using named placeholders, like you've got here, is way better but isn't supported in `mysqli`. You can even simplify it with `$statement->execute(array('user_name' => $user_name, ...))` to reduce the number of lines required. Nice to see you're using prepared statements, though!

Comment: **WARNING**: Maybe it's too late for this project, but writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and never store passwords as plain-text.

Comment: @tadman: who do i change it to PDO?

Comment: @EmilyP Have you looked at *Example #1* of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php)? Also never store password as a plain readable text, always perform [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on raw password before inserting it into the table.

Comment: You're pretty close, it mostly involves changing how you define the connection. [Here's a crash course on PDO](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059) if you need one, but the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) is also pretty good and I'd encourage anyone learning PDO to give it a read, there's a lot of answers in there.

Comment: Can anybody tell me I am trying to add `?>` to my answer in the last code and when I add it so every code turns into simple plan text..It might be a bug..Can anyone check that please???

Comment: You are running the function before defining it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no `bindValue()` method in `mysqli`, `PDO` has. So here are the two approaches to solve your problem:

**1)[`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) method:**

Use `bind_param()` method to bind variables to your prepared statement. So your `new_user()` function should be like this:

```
function new_user($user_name, $password, $email,$con){
    $query = "INSERT into users (user_name, password, email) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
    $statement = $con->prepare($query);
    $statement->bind_param("sss", $user_name, $password, $email);
    if($statement->execute()){
        echo 'Successfully created new user';
    }else{
        // query failed
    }
}
```

NOTE: Since you're passing the connection handler `$con` to this function, there's no need to use `global $con;`. Plus [Globals are evil](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5166527/5517143).

---

**2)[`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) method:**

Keep your `new_user()` function as it is and change this line

```
$con = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $Password, $database);
```

to

```
$con = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$database",$username,$Password);
```

---

**Sidenote:** Never store password as a plain readable text, always perform [salted password hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) on raw password before inserting it into the table.

Comment: Thank you for this ^-^ i used the bottom one and it comes up that i have added a new user however the user never shows up on my database?

Comment: @EmilyP Did you change the `new_user()` method? Also wrap this statement `$statement->execute()` inside if-else block, like this: `if($statement->execute()){ echo 'Successfully created new user'; }else{ echo 'query failed'; }`

Comment: i changed the $con line. It now comes up with query failed.

Comment: @EmilyP Okay, to debug this issue do this. After this line `$con = new PDO(...)` write these lines, `$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false); $con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. And wrap your execute statement inside if-else block like this: `if($statement->execute()){ echo 'Successfully created new user'; }else{ print_r($con->errorInfo()); }`

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'commish.users' doesn't exist in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(23): PDO->prepare('INSERT into use...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(18): new_user('bob', 'password', 'bob@gmail.com', Object(PDO)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php on line 23.

Comment: This is line 23   $statement = $con->prepare($query);

Comment: @EmilyP It says that `users` table doesn't exist in `commish` database, check whether this table actually exists or not, or does it have a different name.

Comment: I fixed that error. i had an s at the end of user and the column user_name didnt have the _ . However i am getting a new error at

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'username' in 'field list' in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php:23 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(23): PDO->prepare('INSERT into use...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php(18): new_user('bob', 'password', 'bob@gmail.com', Object(PDO)) #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Project\controller\addUser.php on line 23

Comment: Never mind i fixed it! Thank you so much for your help ^-^

Answer (score 0):

There's no bindValue() method in mysqli, you should use bind_param()

new_user function :

```
   function new_user ($user_name, $password, $email) 
    {
        global $con;
        $stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT into users (user_name, password, email) VALUES (?,?,?)";
        $stmt->bind_param("sss", $user_name, $password, $email);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt_error = $stmt->error;
        $stmt->close(); 

        if ($stmt_error)
            echo 'Error on create new user: '.$stmt_error;
        else 
            echo 'Successfully created a new user';
    }
```